# highcharts candlestick a candle value

Tags: highcharts

I need a chart where candles show intervals 5 sec
and  next to each other.
You can see my chart on [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m1vn.png).
Type of xAxis is datetime:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxPadding :1.5,
    },
```

and data function is like this:

```
 data: (function() {

            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            time = time.toString().substr(0, 8);

            time = time +'00000';
            time = parseInt(time );
            for (i = -20; i <= 0; i+=5) {


                data.push(
                    {
                        x: time + i*1000,
                        open:  Math.random(), //open
                        high: Math.random()-0.2,//high
                        low: Math.random()+0.4,//low
                        close: Math.random()+0.4//close
                    });


            }

            return data;
        })(),
            visible: true
    }
```

Comment: Your x ( x: time + i*1000,) should be a number, but in your case is string.

Comment: time = parseInt(time ); number?

Comment: Yes, you can use parseInt / parseFloat